# How to use conditional transitions in Qt SCXML statecharts

Tags: c++, qt, state-machine, qtwidgets, scxml

I'm currently trying to understand Qts scxml state charts, and how to properly integrate them in my applications. One problem I stumbled uppon are conditional transitions. To explain how I use conditions here and what goes wrong, I made a minimum viable example:

[image: state chart visualization]

The initial state `s_initial` has two transitions to the states `s_false` and `s_true`. Both transitions are triggered by the same event `t_button_clicked`. Depending on the variable `test_var`, only one transition is possible possible at any time. When another `t_button_clicked` event occurs, the state machine returns to `s_initial`.

To test the state machine I created a simple Qt-Widgets application with one push-button to trigger `t_button_clicked`, and a checkbox to change the variable `test_var`:

*(mainwindow.cpp)*

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , chart(this)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->checkBox, &QCheckBox::clicked, [this](bool checked){
        qDebug() << "> checkbox:" << checked;
        chart.dataModel()->setProperty("test_var", checked);
    });
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::released, [this](){
        qDebug() << "> button";
        chart.submitEvent("t_button_clicked");
    });
    chart.start();
}
```

*(testchart.scxml)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0" binding="early" xmlns:qt="http://www.qt.io/2015/02/scxml-ext" name="TestChart" qt:editorversion="4.14.1" datamodel="ecmascript" initial="s_initial">
    <qt:editorinfo initialGeometry="213.11;86.67;-20;-20;40;40"/>
    <state id="s_initial">
        <qt:editorinfo scenegeometry="213.11;233.50;153.11;183.50;120;100" geometry="213.11;233.50;-60;-50;120;100"/>
        <transition type="external" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_false" cond="!test_var">
            <qt:editorinfo endTargetFactors="11.79;50.87"/>
        </transition>
        <transition type="external" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_true" cond="test_var">
            <qt:editorinfo movePoint="37.73;-3.06" endTargetFactors="19.26;54.39"/>
        </transition>
        <onentry>
            <log expr="&quot;s_initial&quot;"/>
        </onentry>
    </state>
    <state id="s_false">
        <qt:editorinfo scenegeometry="529.21;233.50;469.21;183.50;120;100" geometry="529.21;233.50;-60;-50;120;100"/>
        <onentry>
            <log expr="&quot;s_false&quot;"/>
        </onentry>
        <transition type="external" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_initial">
            <qt:editorinfo movePoint="3.06;9.18" endTargetFactors="88.28;64.08" startTargetFactors="13.98;61.45"/>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <state id="s_true">
        <qt:editorinfo scenegeometry="529.21;419.09;469.21;369.09;120;100" geometry="529.21;419.09;-60;-50;120;100"/>
        <onentry>
            <log expr="&quot;s_true&quot;"/>
        </onentry>
        <transition type="external" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_initial">
            <qt:editorinfo movePoint="-37.73;6.12" endTargetFactors="68.74;85.18" startTargetFactors="14.04;72.02"/>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <datamodel>
        <data id="test_var" expr="false"/>
    </datamodel>
</scxml>
```

As can be seen in the scxml-file, I added logging output to each state-onentry to see whether the state was entered or not. Additionally, I added debugging output to the button - and checkbox-clicks. When I run the application, the console output is not what I would've expected:

```
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_initial"
> checkbox: false
> button
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_false"
> button
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_initial"
> checkbox: true
> button
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_false"
> button
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_initial"
> checkbox: false
> button
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_false"
> button
scxml.statemachine: "" : "s_initial"
```

It doesn't matter what the value of `test_var` is. The state machine always takes the first transition to `s_false`, not checking the condition guards I added. As far as I can tell, I used valid ecmascript expressions in my chart and scxml should be able to choose the right transition according to its [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#SelectingTransitions). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use **setScxmlProperty** instead of **setProperty**

   `chart.dataModel()->setScxmlProperty("test_var", checked, "");`
2. And you may simply use ***_event.data*** for passing checkBox current value.

   `chart.submitEvent("t_button_clicked", ui->checkBox->checked() ? 1:0 );`

```xml
<scxml datamodel="ecmascript" initial="s_initial" name="TestChart" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml">
    <state id="s_initial">
        <onentry>
            <log expr="'s_initial'"/>
        </onentry>
        <transition cond="_event.data==1" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_true"/>
        <transition event="t_button_clicked" target="s_false"/>
    </state>
    <state id="s_false">
        <onentry>
            <log expr="'s_false'"/>
        </onentry>
        <transition cond="_event.data==1" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_true"/>
    </state>
    <state id="s_true">
        <onentry>
            <log expr="'s_true'"/>
        </onentry>
        <transition cond="! (_event.data==1)" event="t_button_clicked" target="s_false"/>
    </state>
</scxml>
```

[statechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6atg.gif)

P.S. You may use the next reference materials for better understanding SCXML (I'm promoting my own website)

- [SCXML Tutorial And Examples](https://alexzhornyak.github.io/SCXML-tutorial/)
- [ScxmlEditor with QtScxmlTester - tool for testing SCXML state charts in realtime](https://alexzhornyak.github.io/ScxmlEditor-Tutorial/)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.